# Understanding sub-second values in a timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp

Lets say we have the following time stamp:

```
2017-03-28 23:59:58.12
```

Should the above time stamp be interpreted as having 120 milliseconds or 12 milliseconds?
Further, if we expect a time stamp to have microseconds precision, should 12 be then considered as 120000 microseconds, or 12 microseconds?

Answer (score 1):

The decimal off of the second should be treated as, well, a decimal.  In your case since

```
0.1 seconds = 100 milliseconds
```

you should interoperate it as `120 milliseconds`.  This rule goes for `microseconds` as well,

```
0.1 seconds = 100000 microseconds
```

So, you could read your time stamp as `120000 microseconds`

[Google`s time converter](https://www.google.com/search?q=millisecond%20to%20second&oq=millisecond%20to%20second&aqs=chrome..69i57j6j0l4.3176j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=seconds%20to%20milliseconds&*) supports decimal fractions if you want to play around with it a bit.